# Проблема редиректа - убрать .php из страниц сайта

Tags: редирект, .htaccess

Здравствуйте, господа. Вот такие правила у меня прописаны в .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

Если перейти по site.ru/city откроется www.site.ru/city.php

Но при этот если перейти по site.ru/city/ то выдает ошибку 500 Internal Server Error. Что можно сделать?

Comment: > Что можно сделать?

выяснить, что вызывает ошибку, потому что никто не гарантирует, что именно редирект не работает и вызывает ее, а не ваши php-файлы

---

Второй RewriteRule не предваряется никакими условиями, поэтому сработает, даже если php-файл отсутствует

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1: Поменяйте строки местами

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Вариант 2: Сделать одну регулярку

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php
```

Comment: спасибо, что откликнулись, но все равно не работают ваши варианты(